# How can I detect whether a socket.io server is connected?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am developing an app using socket.io and appjs. I am having trouble giving a notice to the user when he causes EADDRINUSE by starting two instances of the app, which he is not supposed to.

Socket.io does detect EADDRINUSE, but I only receive a warning written to the console (not sure if stdout or stderr). I wanted an exception, a callback where I have an err parameter, or at the very least a flag to detect whether the connection is OK.

Just to clarify, I am trying to do this from the server side. In the client side I already have a timeout for client-server connections.

How can I do this?

Comment: use code on this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454005/socket-io-node-js-detecting-if-server-is-down, it solved that issue for me perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EADDRINUSE is an error emitted by the net modules. Docs here: http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_port_host_backlog_callback

In short you need to provide a callback to `.on('error'` that will handle the error.

```
server.on('error', function (e) {
  if (e.code == 'EADDRINUSE') {
    console.log('Address in use');
  }
});
```

Comment: Adding an error handler does get me the error. It makes a lot of sense since socket.io works asynchronously. Thank you