# If node server is down. How to get error handling on socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

How can i detect server status ?

```
var socket= io.connect('http://nodeserver.com:3000');
```

Here is my code. If **nodeserver.com:3000** is down, how can i validate server down or up ?

I tried **connect_failed**, **error** events but doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

have you tried doing it like this?

```
this.socket.on('connect_error', function (err) {
    //do something
});
```

in other words, use the connect_error instead of the connect_failed event?

Comment: Thanks for this. I've been searching for a while!

Answer (score -2):

for checking "disconect" of a socket you can you this code :

```
io.socket.on('connect', function(){
  console.log('connected to server ...');

});

io.socket.on('disconnect', function(){
  console.log('Lost connection to server');
});
```